# Matching strings in jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

I have this table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>John Stevenson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>John Stevenson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Jack Stevenson</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I find if there is "Jack Stevenson" and if it true, set this td color to red.

My jQuery code not works:

```
$("table").find("td").each(function () {
  var hiImJohn = $("td:contains('John Stevenson')");
  var td = $(this).text();

  if ( td.indexOf("John Stevenson")  > 0 ) {
      hiImJohn.css({color: "red"});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
$("table").find("td:contains('John Stevenson')").each(function () {
  $(this).css({color: "red"});
});
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/q45cGWpW8ql7FfoNaKDj?p=preview

**EDIT**

Please note, there is no need of each loop either. Updated code will be as follows

```
$("table").find("td:contains('John Stevenson')").css({color: "red"});
```

Comment: There is no need of `each()` you can just use `$("table").find("td:contains('John Stevenson')").css({color: "red"})`

Comment: @Satpal - Thanks. I missed to update that while copy pasting it. Glad you noticed. Will update

Comment: If you're micro-optimising, then there's also no need for `.find` either ... :)

Comment: @freedomn-m - Correct. However, I will like to stick to what I have written above. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("table").find("td").each(function () {
  if($(this).text() == "John Stevenson"){
    $(this).css("background-color:red");
  }
});
```